# What does Parse use for caching (sqlite or CoreData) on the device?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

How does Parse store data on the device (iOS) when there is no connection and for cache? My assumption is they use CoreData, but I couldn't find anything on that online.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they use none of the above. NSCache, maybe.

Comment: An educated guess or something more substantial? @Shmidt :)

Comment: I would have (uneducated) guessed NSCache or home-rolled, too.  If you have an app using the cache, please run it in the simulator and poke around on disk then post clues here.

Comment: @Morgan Wilde take a look at required frameworks. There are no CoreData or sqlite.

Comment: I would guess either NSCache or files. Def not core data.

Comment: @Shmidt you can embed your own sqlite thought.

Comment: Loads of good stuff in the comments, I'm hoping it could be translated into the answer section for other to see.

Comment: @VincentGuerci what's the reason to do that instead of linking? Size of framework will grow.

Comment: @Shmidt there are many reasons not to use iOS sqlite version. You have customized versions of sqlite, which provides features like encryption, extensions and so on. Or you could just want an up to date version. Sqlite is not that big.

Comment: @MorganWilde Are you sure Local data stores are available for iOS parse? Can't find anything on the topic, don't find any file stored, samples does not work w/o network. Looks like to me there is no offline cache (yet?).